# Getting at fsid under Linux? Or an alternate way of identifying filesystems?

Tags: linux, nfs, quota

In an environment with automounted home directories, such that the same filesystem exported by a fileserver may be mounted multiple times on the client, I would like to authoritatively be able to identify whether two mountpoints are in fact the same filesystem.  That is, if the remote server exports:

```
/home
```

And the local client has:

```
# mount
fileserver:/home/l/lars on /home/lars type nfs (rw...)
fileserver:/home/b/bob on /home/bob type nfs (rw...)
```

I am looking for a way to identify that both `/home/lars` and `/home/bob` are in fact the same filesystem.  In theory this is what the `fsid` result of the [statvfs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs) structure is for, but in all cases, for both local and remote filesystems, I am finding that the value of this structure member is 0.

Is this some sort of client-side issue?  Or do most modern NFS servers simply decline to provide a  useful `fsid`?

The end goal of all of this is to robustly interpret the output from the `quota` command for NFS filesystems.  For example, given the example above, running `quota` as myself may return something like:

```
Disk quotas for user lars (uid 6580): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
otherserver:/vol/home0/a/alice
                     12  52428800 52428800               4  4294967295 4294967295        
fileserver:/home/l/lars
                9353032  9728000 10240000          124018       0       0
```

...the problem here being that there exists a quota for me on
otherserver which is visible in the results of the `quota` command,
even though my home directory is actually on a different device.  My
plan was to look up the `fsid` for each mountpoint listed in the
`quota` output and check to see if it matched the `fsid` associated
with my home directory.

It looks like this won't work, so...any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `mountpoint` command. The `-d` switch prints the major/minor device number of the mount point to stdout.

In your case, compare the output of `mountpoint -d /home/lars` to `mountpoint -d /home/bob`.

```
[root@Fruity ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             9.9G  2.5G  7.0G  26% /
/dev/sda1              97M   43M   50M  47% /boot
/dev/sda7             2.0G   68M  1.9G   4% /tmp
/dev/sda3             9.9G  2.8G  6.6G  30% /usr
/dev/sda6             6.0G  1.1G  4.6G  19% /var
/dev/sdb1             400G  263G  138G  66% /data
/dev/sdc1             150G  122G   29G  82% /images
nfs001:/data/chain    36G  1.2G   35G   4% /data/chain
nfs001:/data/src      36G  1.2G   35G   4% /data/src


[root@Fruity ~]# mountpoint -d /data/chain/
0:19

[root@Fruity ~]# mountpoint -d /data/src/
0:19

[root@Fruity ~]# mountpoint -d /data/
8:17
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.  More importantly, looking at the `strace` output for `mountpoint`, it reminds me that I can just call `stat()` on a filesystem and get use the `st_dev` member, which is exactly what `mountpoint` is doing.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. Good to know that works.

Comment: `st_dev` customarily uniquely identifies a device but is not *required* to do so.   For example some POSIX-like implementations set `st_dev=-1` for all NFS filesystems.   To be certain you need to use the combination of `st_dev` and the `st_ino` value of the top directory in the filesystem.   And that is just what `mountpoint` is doing.   Also bear in mind that these techniques do not work for AFS.